# Opendaylight serialize null values issue

Tags: opendaylight, ietf-netmod-yang

I'm developing a project using Opendaylight (oxygen-sr4). I defined objects by Yang. `.yang` file like: `grouping person{ leaf enName{ type string; } leaf zhName{ type string; } }`

When I transmit a person object to the front-end, I found field missing issue if the value of field is null. 
I need: `{"person":{"enName":"allen","zhName":null}}`, but i got: `{"person":{"enName":"allen"}})`

I debugged the project. I found the issue is when serializing the person object(`Person.java` is generated automatically by Yang),`DataNodeContainerSerializerSource` under module `mdsal-binding-dom-codec`
 generated anonymous serialize method and added the `null` checking like this:

```
java.lang.String getZhName = ((java.lang.String) _input.getZhName());
if (getZhName != null) {
    _stream.leafNode("zhName",getZhName);
}
```

`org.opendaylight.mdsal.binding.dom.codec.gen.impl.DataNodeContainerSerializerSource` generated anonymous serialize method:

```
private void emitChild(final StringBuilder sb, final String getterName, final Type childType,
            final DataSchemaNode schemaChild) {
        sb.append(statement(assign(childType, getterName, cast(childType, invoke(INPUT, getterName)))));

        sb.append("if (").append(getterName).append(" != null) {\n");
        emitChildInner(sb, getterName, childType, schemaChild);
        sb.append("}\n");
    }
```

Is there any way to transmit null value field? By modifying configuration of `.yang` file? Or by creating customize class that extends `DataNodeContainerSerializerSource`?

Btw, I found `DataNodeContainerSerializerSource` is deprecated now.

Comment: Try with `{"person":{"enName":"allen","zhName":[null]}}`. That is how empty values should be [encoded in JSON for data modeled with YANG](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7951#section-6.9).

Comment: Thanks for your comment  @predi.

Field type change to `Boolean` when changed the `.yang` file to `leaf zhName{ type empty; }`. I can not transmit string value any more(when the zhName is not null). @predi

Comment: Then this is probably a non-standard implementation. Wouldn't be a first for ODL. I don't use ODL, so can't help, sorry.